# pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget remove margin

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I have a `pyqtgraph.GraphicsLayoutWidget` with one viewbox and one image item .

---

Let `image` be a numpy array representing an image. Consider the following class:

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
class MyGraphicsLayoutWidget(pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget):
    def __init__(self, image):
        super().__init__()
        layout = self.addLayout()
        self.viewbox = layout.addViewBox(lockAspect=True)
        self.image_item = pg.ImageItem(image)
        self.viewbox.addItem(self.image_item)
        self.show()
```

It will show something like:

[image]

How do I remove the black margin?

In `PyQt5` we can use `setContentsMargin(0,0,0,0)` on `layout`. Is there anything similar on `pyqtgraph`?

Comment: Did you try to just do `self.viewbox.setContentsMargin(0, 0, 0, 0)`? Also, GraphicsLayoutWidget already has a layout item in it, so you could just call `self.addViewBox()`.

Comment: Sorry for the very late response. What version of pyqtgraph are you using? If I just put `self.addViewBox` or `self.viewbox.setContentsMargin(0, 0, 0, 0)` like you described, it will give me error saying there is no such attribute. I am using pyqtgraph 0.12.4, python 3.8.13, and pyqt 5.15.7, which my conda just updated for me.

Comment: You probably did the above in the wrong order or without understanding what I wrote. Also, if you read the documentation, it's explained what each function does and what it returns. First you add a viewbox with `self.viewbox = self.addViewBox()`, *then* call `self.viewbox.setContentsMargins()`.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using a ViewBox widget, you also have to set the default padding:
`viewbox.setDefaultPadding(0)`